# How to Apply CSS to ASP:FileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net

How exactly do I style this control?

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<asp:FileUpload id="upload_tb" runat="server" />

#upload_tb
{
  width: 500px;
}
```

Also how can I style the browse button that comes with this control? If it is not possible are there other alternatives?

Edit:

I checked the generated source and asp.net gives the control this id `ctl00_main_content_upload_tb`

I changed the CSS to

```
#ctl00_main_content_upload_tb
{
  width: 500px;
}
```

but it does not stretch the control. It adds padding to the right of the control. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can't officially style an input of type file (*) (which is what the FileUpload control renders on the page) but there are ways using a bit of Javascript &/or CSS - see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html or http://tiagoe.blogspot.com/2010/01/css-style-typefile-tags.html - but it isn't trivial.

(*) It's a security measure

Answer (score 0):

This is possible you can change the FileUpload control using following code.

**Step1: Change FileUpload control with this code on aspx page.**

```html
<label class="file-upload"> <span><strong>Upload Image</strong></span> <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" > </asp:FileUpload> </label>
```

**

```css
.file-upload {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    ;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 1px solid #124d77;
    background: #007dc1;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

    .file-upload:hover {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0061a7), color-stop(1, #007dc1));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0061a7', endColorstr='#007dc1',GradientType=0);
        background-color: #0061a7;
    }

/* The button size */
.file-upload {
    height: 30px;
}

    .file-upload, .file-upload span {
        width: 90px;
    }

        .file-upload input {
            ;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: bold;
            /* Loses tab index in webkit if width is set to 0 */
            opacity: 0;
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        }

        .file-upload strong {
            font: normal 12px Tahoma,sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .file-upload span {
            ;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            /* Adjust button text vertical alignment */
            padding-top: 5px;
        }
```

**